# Jupyter Notebook: how to skip the confirmation after CTRL-C?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 like this:

```
jupyter notebook
```

If I press CTRL-C, it prompts me for confirmation to exit. I need to remove that step. I want Notebook to quit immediately (it's an automation thing, long story). I do not care about any possible side-effects (it's a disposable environment, and CTRL-C really means it's time for Jupyter to go away, no questions asked).

The -y option claims to skip all dialogs, but it does nothing when it comes to the CTRL-C prompt.

How to disable the shutdown prompt in Notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. It turns out that -y does not skip the prompt with Notebook 6.2.0, but it does skip it with 6.3.0 or later.

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/5941

So the solution is to simply upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

While this question has been marked solved, it may be worth pointing out that if a confirmation after sending SIGINT (Ctrl+C) to the jupyter process is a problem, a possible escalation would be to use the `kill` command to send a SIGTERM, or maybe even SIGKILL instead. A well-behaved process will terminate in an orderly fashion after receiving a SIGTERM signal, and a SIGKILL is the quivalent of asking the operating system to kindly murder the offending process in its sleep.